# Index was outside the bounds of the array.C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I've a part of program that have method to generate code (HelmID), to generate it, i've to read from text file to get the latest HelmID. Here's my text file.

```
T001#C001#H001#FullFace#S001#
T001#C001#H002#FullFace#S002#
```

The problem is, the method wont generate to H003 (after H002) and give error message 'Index was outside the bounds of the array'. Here's my method code.

```
public string newHelmetCode()
        {
            string Str, HelmetCode;
            int HelmetInt;
            string[] strArray = new string[5];
            if (new FileInfo("TransDetail.txt").Length == 0)
            {
                HelmetCode = "H001";
                return HelmetCode;
            }
            else
            {
                Str = File.ReadLines("TransDetail.txt").Last();
                strArray = Str.Split(new string[] { "#" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                HelmetCode = strArray[2].Substring(1, 3);
                HelmetInt = Convert.ToInt32(HelmetCode) + 1;

                if (HelmetInt <= 9)
                {
                    HelmetCode = "H00" + HelmetInt.ToString();
                }
                else if (HelmetInt <= 99)
                {
                    HelmetCode = "H0" + HelmetInt.ToString();
                }
                else if (HelmetInt <= 999)
                {
                    HelmetCode = "H" + HelmetInt.ToString();
                }
                return HelmetCode;
            }
        }
```

The error come from this code `HelmetCode = strArray[2].Substring(1, 3);`. It should generate cause i'm using Substring (and convert to int) to get latest number on last row on text file. Any reply would appricate

Comment: Is there perhaps a linebreak after the last line?

Comment: What's the content of 'Str' after the statement Str = File.ReadLines("TransDetail.txt").Last();?

Comment: Please debug code and make sure error is coming from  HelmetCode = strArray[2].Substring(1, 3);.  MAKE SURE LAST LINE IS NOT EMPTY IN TEXT file

Comment: Btw, you dont need the `if...else if...else if...` part, this is sufficient: `HelmetCode = "H" + HelmetInt.ToString("D3")`

Comment: Thanks to user2960398 and Romano Zumbe
there is a empty line afre H002 because of i use 
writeline on stream writer that cause an empy line

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is a linebreak after the last line or something like that. You can use LINQ to the only the relvant lines:

```
var lineFields = File.ReadLines("TransDetail.txt")
    .Select(line => line.Split(new string[] { "#" }, StringSplitOptions.None))
    .Where(arr => arr.Length >= 5)
    .ToArray();

if(lineFields.Length > 0)
{
    string[] lastFields = lineFields.Last();
    int helmetInt;
    bool valid = int.TryParse(lastFields[2].Substring(1), out helmetInt);
    // check if it's valid otherwise log/throw error

    // you dont need the if...else if...else if... part, this is enough: 
    string helmetCode = "H" + helmetInt.ToString("D3");
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the `strArray` has less than three items in it.

You should check on the length first. (My guess is that the last line is an empty line btw):

```
if (strArray.Length >= 3)
{
    // do
}
```

You should also check the length of the string you want to `Substring`, because when the `length < 1`, you will get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

So check the length:

```
string test = strArray[2];

if (test.Length > 1)
{
    // do
}
```